# AngularJS: Empty value when access in view

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm newbie in *AngularJS*, I have a question, please explain to me the reason of my mistake. At first, I have a factory name `CategoryParent` with this function declared like this,

```
routerApp.factory('CategoryParent', function($http) {

    var categoryParentFactory = {};
    var hostCMSAPI="http://***.***.***.***:****";

    // get all categories
    categoryParentFactory.allCategoryParents = function() {
      console.log("call get allCategoryParents");
     return  $http.get(hostCMSAPI+'/api/categoryparents/');

    };
    .......
```

and a controller call this function named `categoryParentController`:

```
 .controller('categoryParentController', function(CategoryParent,$scope) {
        console.log("cateParent ctrl");
        $scope.processing=true;
        $scope.dataList=[];

            $scope.getAllCategoryParents=function(){
              CategoryParent.allCategoryParents().success(function(response){
                    $scope.processing = false;
                    $scope.list=response;
             });
```

I'm using `ui.router` like this (nested view):

```
.state('home.cateParentMenu',{
            url:'/cateParentMenu',
            templateUrl:'categoryParentTop.html',
            controller:'categoryParentController',
            controllerAs:'categoryParent'

        })
```

Parent view trigger controller function here:

## The Homey Page

This page demonstrates nested views.

```
<a ui-sref=".list" class="btn btn-primary">List</a>
<a ui-sref=".paragraph" class="btn btn-danger">Paragraph</a>
<a ui-sref=".cateParentMenu" class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="getAllCategoryParents()">cateParentMenu</a>
```

and last, the children view come here

data show
{{processing}}
{{list}}
    {{item.cate_parent_name}}

```
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav" >
    data show
    {{processing}}
    {{list}}
        <li data-ng-repeat="item in list.data"><a ui-sref=".detail({cate_parent_id:item.cate_parent_id})"  ng-click="getById(item.cate_parent_id)"   ui-sref-active="active" id="{{item.cate_parent_id}}">{{item.cate_parent_name}}</a></li>
        </ul>


    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div ui-view=""></div>
        <!--<div ui-view="serviceRef"></div>-->
        <!--<div ui-view="categoryRef"></div>-->
    </div>
```

I set `$scope.list` and `$scope.processing` to transfer result to view. But in view I show `{{list}}`, nothing appears and `{{processing}} = true` ???

Why? please help me, many thanks to all your suggests.

Comment: Whether request is going to factory function and is it returning data ??

Comment: yes! It return data when I log response. Everything look ok. But in view nothing appear....

Answer (score 0):

**Controller**

Fix `$scope.dataList=[];` to `$scope.list=[];`

Comment: Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope <- CategoryParent

Comment: Sorry, it's my mistake, you don't need to make any change to your factory, just leave it as it is. The only change you need is `$scope.list=[];` in your controller. I update my answer

Comment: Thank you, but still error. Output is:
data show true []

Comment: Did you click the button to run `getAllCategoryParents()` function ?

Comment: yes, I did. it can jump to that function, I write out log : $scope.processing value (FALSE) & $scope.list = Obj result. But in view, {{processing}} = true, {{list}} = []

Comment: It's difficult to debug without jsfiddle. Is your child view in `categoryParentController` scope? Or maybe `ng-controller="categoryParentController"` is needless in parent view. It's worth to test with `this` in controller instead of `$scope`.